# how to create a task that uses a text file in IntelliJ eduTools

Tags: intellij-idea, resources

I am trying to create a task that needs to read from a file in IntelliJ EduTools.
I tried creating a directory at the root of the course and marked it as a resources, I tried putting the actual file in the src component of the Task. I tried a number of locations for the resource file.

Here's what I got. Once I created a resource file at the top level of the project, the task was able to work. However, the tests were not able to find the file. (I then tried creating a test resource directory in many locations without success).

Where should I place resource files for Tasks and Tests to run in IntelliJ Edu Tools?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the files for tasks into the task directory and files for tests into the *tests* directory. Path to file should be defined like this:

./filename.extension - for task files
./tests/filename.extension - for test files

Comment: The test works. I also needed to "include" the file by going to "Context Menu->Course Creator->Include file". 
I could not get the Task file work. I tried putting it under Task1 (my task) and into src. Neither worked with ./filename.ext  anything else I need to set up?